# Unsigned equivalent of a negative FixNum

Tags: ruby, types, unsigned, fixnum

How do I determine the unsigned interpretation of a negative FixNum?

```
# unexpected, true
(~0b01111011).to_s(2) == ("-" + (~0b01111011).abs.to_s(2))

# expected, false
~0b01111011 == 0b10000100
```

How would I write a function such that:

```
123.unsigned_not(8) == 132
```

Or alternatively:

```
-124.unsigned(8) == 132
```

Edit: I could do this via strings, but the solution is far from satisfying

```
class Fixnum
  def unsigned_not(bits=16)
    to_s(2).rjust(bits,'0').gsub(/[01]/, '0' => '1', '1' => '0').to_i(2)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Fixnum#~` operator does [Two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s%5Fcomplement) and Ruby uses internally arbitrary big numbers & arithmetic, so if you want to do an inversion on a fixed base, you need to work in required bounds and interpret results accordingly:

```
class Fixnum
  def neg(base=8)
    # xor with max in specific base
    self ^ (2**base - 1)
  end
end

132.neg             # 123
123.neg             # 132
~-124.neg           # 132
132.to_s(2)         # 1000010
132.neg.to_s(2)     # 0111101
# different result for a different base, as expected
132.neg(16).to_s(2) # 111111110111101
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you could try this test :

```
(0x800000FF & ~0b01111011) == (0x800000FF & 0b10000100)
```

assuming 0x... standing for Hex constant
and & standing for the AND operator for the language you are dealing with.
leading 0x8 would force 32 bits extension ?

Comment: Hm I really like this direction but the result of your comparison is false